# Research experience not matching what I want to study in the future. Problem?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, graduate-school, computer-science, undergraduate

My research experiences have been in Information Theory and Computational Number Theory.

However, in my PhD in Computer Science, I want to do research with professors working with computer algorithms, computational complexity, graphs etc.

Will it be an issue for me, when I apply for the top 20 grad schools, that my research experience does not align well that closely with what I want to study?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you will stay in the US, this change of field shouldn't be a problem. However, limiting your applications to the top 20 grad schools *will* be a problem and you risk finding no open slot in so narrow a field. You are naming at a very small target that has a lot of very highly qualified applicants.

If you start with a bachelors it will be easier to switch as you have more time to align with the new field. With a masters would be a bit tight, since you still need to pass qualifying exams in most places and these are usually broad based requiring some advanced coursework for most students.

But a lot of people starting with a bachelors make much broader jumps to the final research area.

Cast a broad net, top 50 at least. There are a lot of good R1 universities in US. Have a few backups at minimum.

Comment: Okay so to clarify, I am currently an undergradute senior in college. I have had two REUs in Information Theory and Number Theory, both of which can still be considered parts of the theory side of CS. I want to study theoretical computer science for my PhD also but I want to work with professors with expereince in computer algorithms, complexity, graphs etc. I am concerned because my undergrad research was not in algorithms.

Comment: Not a problem, but cast a broader net than top 20. Seriously. I don't care how good you are.

Comment: Yes, of course, thanks!
But my research experiences shouldn't be a problem right?
I will be writing about number theory and all in my personal statement but I am just worried that the algorithm prof reading my SoP might not know a lot about my reseearch/what I did because of his potentially limited background in Number Theory. That is one part I am worried about.

Comment: Presumably you have undergrad CS courses, including algorithms. I've been assuming that. But you'll have time before serious research begins. Pass those qualifiers.

Comment: Yes, those I do!

Comment: Also,  I will be writing about number theory and all in my personal statement but I am just worried that the algorithm prof reading my SoP might not know a lot about my reseearch/what I did because of his potentially limited background in Number Theory. That is one part I am worried about.